# (not really) Dynamic Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic

I have some template data with following code:

```
uint idCounter = 0;

template <typename T>
class Foo : BaseFoo
{
    static const uint FOO_ID;
}

template <typename T>
const uint Foo::FOO_ID = idCounter++;
```

This gives every implementation of `Foo` an unique id => No need to put IDs manually, and the final count of implementations is just the value of `idCounter`.

**Now i want to do the following:**

```
std::vector<std::array<BaseFoo*, idCounter>>
// or
std::vector<BaseFoo*[idCounter]>
```

**and not:**

```
std::vector<std::vector<BaseFoo*>>
```

**Why?**

I need the inner data to be aligned! Vector just allocates space somewhere, and not directly inside the outer vector.

**Problem:**

We all know, that dynamic arrays are not allowed (without calling new), because `idCounter` is not const-expression. But idCounter is known at compile time. The compiler knows how many implementations of `template Foo` are used in the program. And this amount will not change during runtime. I would say, it is known at compile time. Or maybe after compile time but before runtime ;)

**Question:**

Is there a way to use some pattern, that allows me to do the same thing, but with memory alligned array with that size?

Comment: If you know the size of the `vector` at compile time you might want to consider `std::array<T, size>`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what are trying to do.

Comment: std::array<T, size> is not working, because my counter is not a const-expression. I edited the question to make it clearer (i hope so)

Comment: Your `BaseFoo*` array within `vector` is just a 2-dimensional array where one dimension is static. You can write a wrapper and use `vector<BaseFoo*>` with basic arithmetic. Where `j`th item in `i`th array would be `i * idCounter + j`.

Comment: That's a good one! Didn't thought of that. But this will only work if the inner is not wrapped inside a struct with additional data or something else. But again, good one!